# Adding manager in django form

Tags: python, django, forms, field, userform

I want to create user from extended Profile model , its done using api request , but from form it is not working . In api request body I am passing three fields only name,email,and phone_number, so that password is making through random automatically.

```
class ProfileManager(model.Manager):

    def create(self, email,phone_number, **kwargs):
        password=str(random.random())[2:8]
        user = User(username=phone_number)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        profile = Profile(
            user=user,
            email=email,
            **kwargs
        )
        profile.save()
```

if am using form like

```
class CustomerCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name =forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=32)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=['email','name','phone_number']
```

this ,it making error like user (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
because my profile model look like

```
class Profile(models.model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length= 15, null=True, blank=True)
```

So from here i understood that ProfileManager is not dependent with form, so i need to make def validate(self,attrs) like function and differet manger for form , but i don't know how to do this due to newbie.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would depend on how you are using your form... I see two solutions:

### Don't commit when saving form

If you set the *commit* argument of the form *save* method to False, the model object will have its attribute updated according but not saved in the database.
This allows you to further work on it before persisting the changes.

For example, in a *CreateView*, you would override the *form_valid* method if your are using [Class Based View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)  # obj.save() not called by the form
    obj.user = self.request.user  # or other user source
    obj.save()  #  model instance saved in db with validated constraints

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

If using function views, the idea is the same:

```
def my_view(request):
    # Omitting HTTP method check for simplicity
    my_form = Form(data=request.Post)

    if my_form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

# template stuff goes here
```

### Pass the missing values in the form

This is not as clean as the first one...
You override the *constructor* and *save* method of your form to add the missing fields value:

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
# Meta here

```
def __init__(self, user, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def save(self, commit=True):
    # add missing fields
    self.instance.user = self.user
    # and proceed with normal form flow
    return super().save(commit)
```

Comment: i didn't get the def form_valid function, where should I put that one, i tried that in class CustomerCreateForm(forms.ModelForm)  but didnt worked ,any ways, your second "def save()" solution worked for me. , thank you very much @Nicolas Apprio

Comment: The form_valid is a Class Based View method, I'll edit the response to point this out... Anyway, this is just the next part after your form..is_valid() step

Answer (score 1):

You are leaving out `user` field on your `CustomerCreateForm` fields attribute. And also you are setting `auth_user` instead of just `user`? So add it on the fields attribute, and also set the user field to be blank like so:

```py
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

Since the user is created manually after submitting the form.

Comment: sorry to mention that that's not an error , i forget rename that field while asking the question

Comment: Can you post where ProfileManager is on the Profile model? And also View code ?

Comment: profile manager is located in model.py , and i am getting that in success way while using serializers and API , my only problem was with forms, anyways thanks for responding, i got solution from @Nicolas